# Unable to delete or create azure aks instances

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

After a few days of testing Azure aks, I find myself in a situation where existing aks instances don't clean up when I delete the parent resource group (or with az aks delete) and I am also unable to create new aks instances. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Curent state:

```
rbigeard@ROMAINWORK199A:~|⇒  az aks list -o table
Name           Location    ResourceGroup    KubernetesVersion    ProvisioningState    Fqdn
-------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------------  -------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
K8Cluster      westus2     K8               1.8.1                Failed
K8Cluster2     westus2     K8               1.8.1                Failed
K8test         westus2     K8               1.7.7                Failed
K8TestCluster  westus2     K8Test           1.7.7                Failed
myK8Cluster    westus2     myK8Group        1.7.7                Failed               myk8cluste-myk8group-5ec36a-b448f367.hcp.westus2.azmk8s.io
myK8s          westus2     myK8Group        1.8.1                Failed
```

Creation error in a brand new empty resource group in westus2:

```
az aks create --name K8TestCluster --resource-group K8Test  --agent-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 27476ee2-fea2-406a-83bd-89de89d7aec1. getAndWaitForManagedClusterProvisioningState error: <nil>
```

The version of the cli is (I run it in WSL):

```
az --version
azure-cli (2.0.20)

acr (2.0.14)
acs (2.0.18)
appservice (0.1.19)
backup (1.0.2)
batch (3.1.6)
batchai (0.1.2)
billing (0.1.6)
cdn (0.0.10)
cloud (2.0.9)
cognitiveservices (0.1.9)
command-modules-nspkg (2.0.1)
component (2.0.8)
configure (2.0.12)
consumption (0.1.6)
container (0.1.12)
core (2.0.20)
cosmosdb (0.1.14)
dla (0.0.13)
dls (0.0.16)
eventgrid (0.1.5)
extension (0.0.5)
feedback (2.0.6)
find (0.2.7)
interactive (0.3.11)
iot (0.1.13)
keyvault (2.0.13)
lab (0.0.12)
monitor (0.0.11)
network (2.0.17)
nspkg (3.0.1)
profile (2.0.15)
rdbms (0.0.8)
redis (0.2.10)
resource (2.0.17)
role (2.0.14)
servicefabric (0.0.5)
sql (2.0.14)
storage (2.0.18)
vm (2.0.17)

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/rbigeard/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.6.1 (default, Oct 18 2017, 20:41:18)
[GCC 4.8.4]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal
```

Comment: aks is in preview, you should probably contact some one from the aks team on twitter or somewhere, i dont think there is a support (official) for preview features

Comment: I am checking on the query and would get back to you soon on this.

Comment: I have contacted Azure Support and they asked me to create this thread ;-) They are looking at it. Glad t see I am not the only one.

Comment: @RomainBigeard I get the same error message with you, please delete that group via Azure portal.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I have managed to delete the groups through the portal (which did not work yesterday) and I have been able to create a new instance. So this seems resolved for me now.

Comment: I have the same issue - I just get a "Failed" when creating the k8s cluster

Comment: @RomainBigeard we can create AKS in west us 2 now, please check it:)

Comment: @koe That problem is fixed now, please check it:)

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the service disruption. There was a provisioning/capacity issue that impacted the regional Kubernetes service which was resolved today. You can view the resolution updates @ https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2

Active status on additional known Kubernetes issues are being tracked @ https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues.

Answer (score 1):

For now, we can create AKS in west US 2, it is working now.

[image]

Comment: Hi, we can create AKS in west US 2 now, please check it, thank you for your question, Azure Team have fixed it now:)

Comment: @RomainBigeard We have a general service outage in West US 2 that we are investigating.During the time we investigate, cluster creations in West US 2 will not be possible and existing customers might not work. We will [update this thread](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/master/annoucements/service_outage_2017-11-09.md) when we fix the issue.We apologize for the inconvenience.